# Why does VSTO Add-in project need migration?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, vsto

I'm using Visual Studio 2015. I have Office 2003 and 2010 installed on my computer.

I've created a Word 2010 VSTO Add-in. I tried to build it and debug on Word 2010 and it worked OK.

Then I closed Visual Studio, and opened it ones more and opened a solution with my VSTO project - but I can't open it without one-way upgrade. It needs to be migrated.

If I agree to one-way upgrade my project builds OK, but I can't debug:

> You cannot debug or run this project, becuase the required version of the Microsoft Office application is not installed

In csproj file I can see that it indeed require wrong version of Office (OfficeVersion should be 14.0 for Office 2010):

```
<ProjectExtensions>
<VisualStudio>
  <FlavorProperties GUID="{BAA0C2D2-18E2-41B9-852F-F413020CAA33}">
    <ProjectProperties HostName="Word" HostPackage="{29A7B9D7-A7F1-4328-8EF0-6B2D1A56B2C1}" OfficeVersion="15.0" VstxVersion="4.0" ApplicationType="Word" Language="cs" TemplatesPath="VSTOTemplates" DebugInfoExeName="#Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Word\InstallRoot\Path#WINWORD.EXE" DebugInfoCommandLine="/w" AddItemTemplatesGuid="{51063C3A-E220-4D12-8922-BDA915ACD783}" />
    <Host Name="Word" GeneratedCodeNamespace="WKP_EditorTools" IconIndex="0">
      <HostItem Name="ThisAddIn" Code="ThisAddIn.cs" CanonicalName="AddIn" CanActivate="false" IconIndex="1" Blueprint="ThisAddIn.Designer.xml" GeneratedCode="ThisAddIn.Designer.cs" />
    </Host>
  </FlavorProperties>
</VisualStudio>
```

But when I change it to 14.0 and reopen, it needs to be migrated ones again!

What's going on here? Should I downgrade to Visual Studio 2010...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to install any more Visual Studios. I personally make add-ins for Office 2007, 2010 and 2013 (and now 2016), using any version of VS from 2010 to 2015. You just need to set your project a little bit. The attribute OfficeVersion="15.0" doesn't make a big difference for you (actually, I am not sure it changes anything at all), but the attribute

> DebugInfoExeName="#Software\Microsoft\Office\**15.0**\Word\InstallRoot\Path#WINWORD.EXE

defines, which version of Word you are using for debug. You can change the path to the desired one.

If later you will install more versions of MS Office (I believe you need to, because how else you can test compatibility), you can easily switch starting version of Office by setting

> the project properties -> Debug -> Start external program - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\WINWORD.EXE (or another valid path)

Also, your project has a few interop references. It doesn't make a big difference which version to use, they have almost the same features, but I would recommend to use the newest one you have (I think Visual Studio already upgraded it when you chose one way upgrade).

So, after all, you have templates only for two versions of Office, but you can set them to fit your needs.

Comment: As I wrote in my first post "But when I change it to 14.0 and reopen, it needs to be migrated ones again!"

Comment: You don't need to change it anyway. You can debug any version you want anyway, changing the path to winword.exe. And you can change interop version in references, so OfficeVersion="15.0" doesn't make any difference for you.

Comment: You're right! Setting the Start external program in debug properties fixed the issue, now I can debug under VS 2013.

Answer (score 0):

In general Visual Studio Tools for the Office System templates (VSTO) in Visual Studio only support the last two current versions of office for the time Visual Studio was released in.

Visual Studio 2010: Office 2007 ("Office 12"), Office 2010 ("Office 14"), Visual Studio 2012: Office 2010, Office 2013 ("Office 15"), Visual Studio 2013: Office 2010, Office 2013. Visual Studio 2015 is currently on Office 2013 and Office 2016.

You are however not required to downgrade to Visual Studio 2010, you can install versions of Visual Studio side by side. I have Visual Studio 2010, 2012, 2013 and 2015 all installed on one machine.

Be aware that manually changing your Office PIA references to later Office versions is possible but as you don't upgrade the VSTO plumbing in the project there will be a mismatch between the VSTO version the template was designed for and the Office version you target. This can break your project later on.

If you -don't- want to use the VSTO tooling it is recommended to avoid using the VSTO templates and simply start with a blank project and add the references to Office that you want to address in your application. By doing so you can at any time switch the references to other Office versions if you want to target a different version.

Comment: I had the same problem when I tried to use VS 2013 with Office 2010, but I'll try downloading 2010. I need to downgrade, I have no more space on my disk, so one version needs to go :)

Comment: On Visual Studio 2010 it worked like a charm. I'm quite dissapointed that I can't use the newest VS...

Comment: @Maarten van Stam Your answer is wrong and at least misleading. The only truth that you don't have templates in visual studio except for two last versions of Office. But you absolutely can set project yourserlf for any version of MS Office.

Comment: @AlexButenko Feel free to point out where my answer was wrong and misleading. My information came from Software Design Reviews with the VSTO Product Group but can also be found online in official statements: [https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6c21a8b4-40a1-48cc-b287-c9e678e0d082/how-many-versions-of-visual-studio-tools-for-office-vsto-are-there-and-what-are-the-differences?forum=vsto]. I am well aware of the -unsupported- scenarios but I like to stay away from that when helping others fix their problem.

Comment: Ok, suppose it is something bad to set project except for templates. How do you write add-ins if you need them to suport every version from 2007 to 2016 at the same time then?

Comment: You don't use the VSTO templates in that case. If you need Office Addins to support 'all' versions of Office you start a blank project, use the Office Object Model, by adding PIA references to your applications/class library to the lowest Office version you want to support. If you add references to higher versions than the lowest version you want to support you risk breaking things by calling Object Model features that are not available in the lower versions. But this is a complete different question of course.

Comment: Edited the answer, hoping to clear things up a bit. Manually changing the references is a risk you need to take into account. VSTO templates are specifically designed to match their Office versions.